# How to join two tables with JOIN ON

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables. The first one, let's call it "Orders", has two columns: Item and Order_date. The second one (Payments) has three columns: Item, Order_date and Payment.

Let's assume item nr.1 is ordered three times on different days, but payment is only for one order (second table has only one row). The question is, how to join the tables, that in the end we would see all the orders of item nr.1 and the payments if there are such. If not, it should be left blank.

I tried:

```
LEFT JOIN payments
ON orders.item=payments.item AND 
orders.order_date=payments.order_date
```

but I get only the one order with payment as a result.
Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: Use where condition: WHERE table.column is not null or table.column is null

Comment: Is that one payment is for all 3 orders?

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. When clear this will be a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. [ask]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL for the LEFT JOIN statement

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Payments ON Orders.Item = Payments.Item;
```

Comment: This assumes item is an ID number.  If that isn't the case, it would be wise to create an OrderID in the Orders table and a PaymentID in the Payments table.  The payments table also would need a link to the OrderID.  In this case, you also wouldn't need to duplicate order_date and item in the payment table.

Comment: Hi again.... ;) Sorry if I bothered you with my question.... But thanks for the answers anyway... I tried my code again: LEFT JOIN payments
ON orders.item=payments.item AND 
orders.order_date=payments.order_date.... And now it works perfectly! Now it shows all three orders: one with payment and two - without. I do not now, what was wrong first time...